# Reading 100gb xml file in hadoop

Tags: xml, file, hadoop

I'm coding a sort of word count in hadoop ( for now on standalone pseudo-distributed virtual machine running on vmware player ).

I have a single huge 100GB xml file to read ( close to 125 millions of rows ). I read it line by line, and for each word i put it in a FileHashMap where key is the word, and value is the occurrency.

I used the standard BufferedReader to read the file, but it was too sloo, so i started using the apache commons io libraries to read the file, and it is really faster then before,

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(theFile, "UTF-8");
try {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String line = it.nextLine();
        // do something with line
    }
} finally {
    LineIterator.closeQuietly(it);
}
```

but sooner or later ( close to 40 millions of rows ), it become again slow ( i suppose for the swap on hd as the memory run out ... am i right?)

So the question is: which solution ( configuration, data structure ... ) i have left to solve the problem?

Comment: This depends on how many distinct words there are and how big the in-memory map gets.  You might be better off processing this in two passes, one to extract the words to a temp file or stream, and the second to sort and then count without having to have all the words in memory.  Can you post a sample of the XML? Without a better description of your ultimate goal it's hard to provide useful advice.

Comment: the xml file's pattern is the classical ( and repetitive ) 

<tag1>... <tag n> text here </tag1>...</tag n>

i remove tags and use a tokenizer for the "text here" part ( i also have a set of 900 words, if a token match with one of them is removed ).

to further restrict the memory usage i used the FileHashMap (keys are in memory,values are serialized on the disk)

I didn't understand your hint...if i already have all words in a file, why i should extract them in another temp file?

i was wondering if there was any configuration of the vmware player or java vm  that could help me :)

Comment: If the words are in an XML document, the document is probably not sortable.  If you extract the raw words to a stream containing only ONE word per line and nothing else, you can then sort the stream and determine word counts without storing anything in memory.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just use mapreduce?

Comment: I will make a canonical use of hadoop in the second part of my assignment, i need a "classical" word count too without use of any cluster